# How to skip deleted contact while getting gmail contact?

Tags: c#, gdata, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I get all the gmail account contact by following code.

```
try
{
    Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> Contacts = contactRequest.GetContacts();
    Contact entity;     //local entity
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
    foreach (Google.Contacts.Contact objContact in Contacts.Entries)
    {
        try
        {
            entity = new Contact();
            entity.AddrType = (int)GroupTypes.LocalContact;
            entity.UserID = DataHelper.EmployeeID;
            entity.GmailContactId = objContact.Id;
            entity.GmailContactEtag = objContact.ETag;
            entity.FirstName = objContact.Name.FullName;
            contactList.Add(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    return contactList;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
```

Above code returns all the contacts including deleted contacts. I want to skip deleted contact. 
I just need to get contacts which are not deleted.
Please suggest appropriate way.

Comment: check objContact see if there is a deleted attribute should be true or false.

Comment: @DaImTo, I have tried. There is objContact.Deleted attribute but it doesn't work. It returns false for all the contacts.

Comment: Try digging around in the source code maybe you can find something there. https://github.com/google/google-gdata   Gdata APIs are old and no longer well documented or supported.

Comment: @DaImTo I have found. User need to set ShowDeleted to false and pass it in query.

Comment: Good job post it as an answer and accept it for the next person :)

Answer (score 1):

User can pass in the query.

```
ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
query.ShowDeleted = false;
Feed<Google.Contacts.Contact> Contacts = contactRequest.Get<Google.Contacts.Contact>(query)
```